# Redux Dev Tools failing when embedding inside Provider alongside React Router

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-devtools

I was following the Redux tutorials creating the Todo app and I tried applying [Redux Dev Tools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools-log-monitor) and tried embedding it under my `Provider` alongside `React Router` however I get this error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
    in Provider (created by Root)
    in Root
```

Here is how I'm trying to embed it:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todos from './reducers'
import DevTools from './components/DevTools'

const store = createStore(todos, {}, DevTools.instrument())

const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/(:filter)" component={App} />
        </Router>
        <DevTools /> <!-- If I remove DevTools everything is fine -->
    </Provider>
)

Root.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

render(<Root store={store} />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

My `DevTools` implementation is just completely grabbed from the [documentation](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/blob/master/docs/Walkthrough.md#containersdevtoolsjs) Here's my current dependencies:

```
{
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps anyone, I'm keeping this question open. So I've solved this by putting the `<DevTools />` adjacent with the `<Provider />` component and passed in the `store` as well.

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/(:filter)" component={App} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    {!isProduction && <DevTools store={store} /> }
)
```

Also I indicated if the codebase is for production if not then show the `<DevTools/>` component, this is so when you build your application the Redux DevTools won't get included in the bulk of your app.